# jQuery change div to HTML5 contenteditable and pass to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, contenteditable

Current I have the following div

```
 <div class="tag-header">
    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
 </div>
```

And I add the contenteditable to the div with .attr

```
$('.tag-header').attr("contenteditable", "true");
```

But my problem is how to pass the value to php and post to database?
*NOTE: I'm not ready to use ajax just normal php submit.

Comment: You'd probably have to put a hidden input called ContentEditable in your form, then set it to true when you add the attribute, then when you post the form, you will be able to retrieve the value of the ContentEditable input

Comment: Use `<form>` and `<input>` fields instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pHKdC/)

Update html to

```
<form>
<div class="tag-header">
    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
 </div>
<input type="hidden" id="tagval" />
</form>
```

Then use the focusout event to bind

```
$(".tag-header").focusout(function() {
   $("#tagval").val($(".tag-header").text());
});
```

Submit the form to get the value in  PHP.

Comment: there is 1 more question. The contenteditable has previously contain text and how to get the previous text if the user type in nothing?

Comment: `$("#tagval").val($(".tag-header").text());` add this line just above `$('.tag-header').attr("contenteditable", "true");`

Comment: doesn't work. Can you check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/pHKdC/1/

Explanation inside

Comment: it only works without .focusout but without .focusout it won't sync when i typing within the contenteditable div

Comment: ic, i just got what you meant "add" and i was move the line.
Thanks again.